# Button disappears

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have next Layout (TOP: Two Spinner Half: TableLayout Down: Button) , I have filled the TableLayout with WebService with...
"for (int i = 0; i < ljsonArray.length(); i++)"

But when the last record of WebService show in the TableLayout, the button disappeared, what's wrong?

Regards

```
//Click botton
public void consultar(View v){
    // Building Parameters to call WebService
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String url = "http://futcho7.com.mx/MiScore/WebService/gettablapos.php";
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_cliente", numCte.get(0)));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_sucursal", numSuc.get(0)));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_torneo", Integer.toString(idTorneo)));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_jornada", Integer.toString(idJornada)));

    new AsyncConector(this, url, params, this).execute();
}
```

Method to fill the TableLayOut

```
public void showTablaPos(){
    TableLayout tablaPos = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla_pos);
    //Create table row header 
    TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
    tr_head.setId(10);
    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    //tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //Se crean los header
    TextView label_equipo = new TextView(this);
    label_equipo.setId(20);
    label_equipo.setText("EQUIPO");
    label_equipo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_equipo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_equipo);

    TextView label_jj = new TextView(this);
    label_jj.setId(20);
    label_jj.setText("JJ");
    label_jj.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_jj.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_jj);

    TextView label_jg = new TextView(this);
    label_jg.setId(20);
    label_jg.setText("JG");
    label_jg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_jg.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_jg);

    TextView label_je = new TextView(this);
    label_je.setId(20);
    label_je.setText("JE");
    label_je.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_je.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_je);

    TextView label_jp = new TextView(this);
    label_jp.setId(20);
    label_jp.setText("JP");
    label_jp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_jp.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_jp);

    TextView label_gf = new TextView(this);
    label_gf.setId(20);
    label_gf.setText("GF");
    label_gf.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_gf.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_gf);

    TextView label_ge = new TextView(this);
    label_ge.setId(20);
    label_ge.setText("GE");
    label_ge.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_ge.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_ge);

    TextView label_dif = new TextView(this);
    label_dif.setId(20);
    label_dif.setText("DIF");
    label_dif.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_dif.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_dif);

    TextView label_ptos = new TextView(this);
    label_ptos.setId(20);
    label_ptos.setText("PTOS.");
    label_ptos.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_ptos.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_ptos);

    tablaPos.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Integer count = 0;
    Integer cuantos = ljsonArray.length();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < ljsonArray.length(); i++) {
            ljsonObject = ljsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                  

            String equipo = (ljsonObject.optString("equ_nombre"));
            Integer jj = (ljsonObject.optInt("jj"));
            Integer jg = (ljsonObject.optInt("jg"));
            Integer je = (ljsonObject.optInt("je"));
            Integer jp = (ljsonObject.optInt("jp"));
            Integer gf = (ljsonObject.optInt("gf"));
            Integer ge = (ljsonObject.optInt("ge"));
            Integer dif = (ljsonObject.optInt("dif"));
            Integer pto = (ljsonObject.optInt("puntos"));

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            if(count%2!=0) tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tr.setId(100+count);
            //tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //Create columns to add as table data
            // Create a TextView to add equipo

            TextView labelEquipo = new TextView(this);
            labelEquipo.setId(200+count); 
            labelEquipo.setText(equipo);
            labelEquipo.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelEquipo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(labelEquipo);

            TextView labelJj = new TextView(this);
            labelJj.setId(200+count); 
            labelJj.setText(Integer.toString(jj));
            labelJj.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelJj.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelJj.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelJj);

            TextView labelJg = new TextView(this);
            labelJg.setId(200+count); 
            labelJg.setText(Integer.toString(jg));
            labelJg.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelJg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelJg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelJg);

            TextView labelJe = new TextView(this);
            labelJe.setId(200+count); 
            labelJe.setText(Integer.toString(je));
            labelJe.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelJe.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelJe.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelJe);

            TextView labelJp = new TextView(this);
            labelJp.setId(200+count); 
            labelJp.setText(Integer.toString(jp));
            labelJp.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelJp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelJp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelJp);

            TextView labelGf = new TextView(this);
            labelGf.setId(200+count); 
            labelGf.setText(Integer.toString(gf));
            labelGf.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelGf.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelGf.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelGf);

            TextView labelGe = new TextView(this);
            labelGe.setId(200+count); 
            labelGe.setText(Integer.toString(ge));
            labelGe.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelGe.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelGe.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelGe);

            TextView labelDif = new TextView(this);
            labelDif.setId(200+count); 
            labelDif.setText(Integer.toString(dif));
            labelDif.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelDif.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelDif.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(labelDif);

            TextView labelPtos = new TextView(this);
            labelPtos.setId(200+count); 
            labelPtos.setText(Integer.toString(pto));
            labelPtos.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            labelPtos.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            labelPtos.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            tr.addView(labelPtos);

            // finally add this to the table row
            tablaPos.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            count++;


        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

XML LayOut

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/verde"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.14"
        android:text="@string/tit_torneo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:text="@string/tit_jornada"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/torneo"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt_torneo" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/jornada"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.98" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabla_pos"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/consulta"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        android:onClick="consultar"
        android:text="Consultar"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You'll want to add your java code, as well, in order to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is actually on the right of your tableLayout.
Change the orientation of the linearlayout to Vertical instead of horizontal.

Moreover the buttonView should be part of the scrollview if you want to see it at the end of the scrollview.

You can also nested all your xml in a Relative layout et add the attribute "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the button and the button will always be visible.

Hope this helps.

EDIT-1:

Have you tried something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/verde"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.14"
            android:text="@string/tit_torneo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:text="@string/tit_jornada"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/torneo"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt_torneo" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/jornada"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.98" />

     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabla_pos"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/consulta"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        android:onClick="consultar"
        android:text="Consultar"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It works for me when I add rows directly in xml.

Comment: Can you explain me what you expect? Do you expect to have your button at the end of the scrollview or do you want it always visible and the scrollview stops above the button? Should it be below the tableview ?

Comment: I expect the button always show on the bottom, if the TableLayout are empty or not

Comment: Elodie? are you here?